# Позиционно-независимый код объектного файла

Tags: c, gcc

Какой код порождает *gcc* без ключа -fPIC?

**1)** Делаю так:

> # gcc -c p1.c
>
> # file p1.o

вывод:

```
p1.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

**relocatable** ведь значит позиционно-независимый код объектного файла?

**2)**

> # gcc -c -fPIC p1.c
>
> # file p1.o

вывод:

```
p1.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

---

Вывод абсолютно такой же.

1. Получается для *.so* можно не указывать `-fPIC`? Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос.
2. Является ли код без `-fPIC` позиционно-независимым?

Comment: А размер файла смотрели? Наверняка другой. Из https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html  -- `-fpic
    Generate position-independent code (PIC) suitable for use in a shared library, if supported for the target machine. Such code accesses all constant addresses through a global offset table (GOT). The dynamic loader resolves the GOT entries when the program starts ... Position-independent code requires special support, .... . For the x86, GCC supports PIC for System V but not for the Sun 386i. Code generated for the IBM RS/6000 is always position-independent`

Comment: Т.о. краткий ответ на оба вопроса -- **нет**. (А `relocatable` это скорее -- *перемещаемый* (т.е. его можно настроить на работу с любого адреса, но однажды настроенный он не обязательно м.б. использован  в других адресах (то, что нужно для .so)))

Comment: размер абсолютно одиаков.
> `но однажды настроенный он не обязательно м.б. использован в других адресах`
можете это раскрыть?

Comment: Один и тот же код функции (скажем, из статической библиотеки) при запуске может оказаться в разных программах в разных местах. При загрузке программы он настраивается в соответствии с конкретным адресом. При разных запусках это могут быть разные адреса (в этом смысле код relocatable). В .so один и тот же код одновременно оказывается в разных адресах разных процессов и он не может быть настроен также, как настраивается остальной код при загрузке программы. Поэтому он д.б. PIC. Это достигается тем, что все внешние ссылки в нем косвенные и идут через GOT (см. в гугле)

Comment: Например, [вот кажется интересная статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106107/) на эту тему